# sidepopupview not scrolling down and scrolling out of bounds

Tags: javafx, gluon

I am using a  SidePopupView layer in my application (constructed with a borderpane node). If the borderpane content has a larger height than the display, there is no scrolling property attached to the sidepopupview allowing to see the hidden content. I have replaced the borderpane by a scrollpane and then I can scroll down the content of the underlining borderpane content. However, it appears that the scrolling goes beyond the limit of the scrollpane/borderpane height (scroll overflow or kind of pull and refresh effect) and shows an ugly white background behind before returning to limit position. Is it a bug or the implementation of the scrolling may be made differently ? I precise that this effect does happen only in android and not in the simulator. Here is the (very simple) example code:

```
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
pane.setPrefHeight(900); // to be sure it goes out of mobile screen.
SidePopupView layer = new SidePopupView(borderPane);
// Show the sidepopupview:
MobileApplication.getInstance().addLayerFactory(name, () -> { 
return layer;});
MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer(name);
```

A related question is : is it possible to embed a ScrollPane in a simple layer ? When I try to do this, it shows nothing:

```
// In a class extending Layer:
ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane(pane);
getChildren().addAll(scrollpane);
// Then showing the layer does nothing:
MobileApplication.getInstance().addLayerFactory(name, () -> { 
return layer;});
MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer(name);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: As commented, hard to say if you don't post the minimal code to reproduce. Until you do, a few tips: if you add a ScrollPane, use `scrollpane.setFitToHeight(true);`, as that will fit the content to the scrollPane viewport. As for overriding layers, please check [this](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#_layers), and mind the use of `layoutChildren()` method.